# What is the C# equivalent of this VBA code?

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have this VBA code that refreshes the data connections on an excel sheet, and I am updating the code a bit and like the reliability of C# as opposed to Visual Basic...

So my question is what is the C# equivalent of this VBA code :

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, True)
wb.Connections(baseName & " POS Report").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
wb.RefreshAll
wb.Connections(baseName & " POS Report").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = True
```

I already tried the logical equivalent in C# but it wasn't working... any help is greatly appreciated!

I have the basics down :

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook ob = excel.Workbooks.Open(eBook[i], 0, true);
ob.Connections(baseName + " POS Report").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = true;
```

Here the error comes for `Connections` where it says "Non-invocable memer 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.Connections' cannot be used like a method"

Comment: a usefull link to learn C# from vb net http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: @bto.rdz thanks! thats a cool converter. I switched to C# because I was better at it than VBA :P Mostly worked on C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Workbooks.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx) returns a [`Workbook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbook.aspx) which has a [`Connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.connections.aspx) member that contains a [`Connections` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.connections.aspx). You can access a single item of those connections using the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.connections.item.aspx) method.

So it should probably look like this:

```
ob.Connections.Item(baseName + " POS Report").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = true;
```

Comment: The documentation for `Item` is a bit sparse.  It seems to suggest that it *creates* a connection object.  And I'm pretty sure that `Item` is not in the [IEnumerable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx).

Comment: This is how it works in VBA though: `Connections(something)` calls the default member of `Connections` which is `Item`, so it’s actually equivalent to `Connections.Item(something)` which would can the be directly translated into C#. That has little to do about its IEnumerable implementation, and I’m actually not sure if iterating the *existing elements* will work at all.

Comment: "creates" is just very bad wording in the documentation. what it means is that it instantiates a new connection, fills in the appropriate properties, and returns it. As opposed to there already being instances of all your connections in an array somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In VB, you are permitted to designate one of the properties or methods of a class as the 'default' member. You can then use any identifier for an instance of that class "as-if" it were a method name, and it will automatically call/access the default member.

In this case, `Connections` is a collection, and the default member of almost all VBA collection classes is a method called `Item` which returns the specified item, by index (number or name).  So, in VB, these two are equivalent:

```
WorkbookConnection x = wb.Connections("foo")
WorkbookConnection x = wb.Connections.Item("foo")
```

C# doesn't have the same concept of a default member, so you can't use the first syntax. The second syntax is just a normal member access, though, so it works fine.